# Integrity certification failing because Facebook thinks my domain is not verified

Tags: facebook

I've verified my domain, but for whatever reason, Facebook refuses to recognize it as such. Every time I submit my integrity certification for a financial service, I get the following message:

> Thank you for submitting your application to advertise cryptocurrency
>   and related products and services on Facebook family apps and
>   services.
>
> As a reminder, you must verify your domain(s) associated with this
>   application. For information on how to verify your domain(s), see our
>   help center article:
>   https://www.facebook.com/business/help/286768115176155 and our
>   developer documentation:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification.
>
> Details on Facebook's policies for advertising restricted financial
>   products and services can be found here:
>   https://www.facebook.com/policies/ads/restricted_content/cryptocurrency_products_and_services
>
> Prior to completing the review of your application, we must confirm
>   the relevant domain(s) have been verified. Please proceed with
>   verifying the domains submitted in your application.

It should be noted that I have attempted this over 15 times. Unfortunately, Facebook does not offer any email, chat or phone support, so I am stranded.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

*In case you need to see it, this is proof that my domain has been verified, along with the added page for which I am trying to advertise.*
[image]